# Success message in wordpress comment form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, comments

I am using `wordpress 3.8`. I am using `comment_form();` 
I need to display a success message on successfully posted comment on blog. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you may try WP-Ajaxify-Comments 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ajaxify-comments/